# Android OnNavigationListener Override?

Tags: java, android, overriding, android-actionbar

I'm implementing a drop-down menu in my actionBar for android, and I'm trying to set up the onNavigationItemSelected behaviour, but I'm being told there is nothing to Override? Any help would be great. Code:

```
    public class DropMenu implements OnNavigationListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        switch (itemPosition) {

        case 0: {

        }

        case 1: {

        }

        case 2: {

        }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Error:

> The method onNavigationItemSelected(int, long) of type MainActivity.DropMenu must override a superclass method

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Eclipse:

Right-click on your project, go to "Properties", select "Java Compiler" on the left, and set the "Compiler compliance level" to 1.6